# Groovy, Scala, Clojure, etc scripts in Android

Tags: java, android, scala, groovy, clojure

I am working on some Forms and Report Builder written in Java which can run on Android as well. At least the Forms and Reports executer. Users can enter simple groovy scripts, which can change simple variables. Now my problems is that groovy won't really work on Android. Is any way that I use instead of Groovy another language. 
Requirements : 
- that language should be compiled and executed in Java
- pass and read variables to the scripts
- the resulted bytecode should run on Android as well, or eventual directly compiled and executed in Android

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/

Comment: Scala works in Android, but the usages I know are that the final apk file can be built in Scala, or that some Scala library can be used in Java Android project. I don't know whether script-like code also works.

Comment: @tim_yates that library keeps being thrown around, it's not embaddable or usable for integration.

Answer (score 1):

Besides tim's variant(SL4A), there are several more java vm's for existing scripting languages.

Be carefull, not every one will serve your purposes, as Android hasn't JVM, it has Dalvik VM instead, wich works differently, and pack and optimise java bytecode, when some JVM scripting languages relay on dynamic class files compilation and execution.

If your tasks are simple, consider Lua. It's an extremely lightweight scripting language, and it has a 2 working pure-Java vm implementations, which will go on android:

1. http://sourceforge.net/projects/luaj/
2. http://code.google.com/p/kahlua/

Answer (score 1):

Version 2.4.0 of Groovy will have Android support.
At the time I'm writing this, the current version is 2.3 and there's still no public beta of 2.4, but you can try right now by building the snapshot like this:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core
$ cd groovy-core
$ ./gradlew clean dist
```

the generated library to be included in your Android Studio project will be target/libs/groovy-test-2.4.0-SNAPSHOT-grooid.jar.
Then you'll need to modify your gradle.build file to include Groovy support; this system looks still in early stages, so please refer to this page for further info: http://melix.github.io/blog/2014/06/grooid.html

Comment: But is this support for runtime scripts or just for compile time use of the language.

Comment: As you can see here: http://melix.github.io/blog/2014/06/grooid2.html you can also do runtime scripting, although stile quite slowly

Comment: Painfully slow. I found out LuaJ is available on Android on its latest version and I don't expect major performance slowdowns with it.